# How do I run a python file from command prompt: not getting any response

Tags: python

How can I run below file?

Here is my code:

main.py

```
def calculation(a, b):
   print(a)
   return a
```

I have tried, py main.py it does not return anything.

Comment: You define the functions `calculation` but do not call it, so it is not executed.

Comment: Your program defines a function, and that is it. It has no output. What *output where you expecting and why*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke that function

```
def calculation(a, b):
   print(a)
   return a

print(calculation(1, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access command line arguments using `sys.argv`.  This is a very minimal example.

**my_prog.py**

```
import sys

def calculation(a, b):
   print(a)
   return a

if __name__ =='__main__':
    a,b = sys.argv[1:]
    calculation(a,b)
```

To run:

```
host$ python3 my_prog.py 1 2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function to run it. Add `calculation(a, b)` to your code with a and b as the values to pass. For example:

```
def calculation(a, b):
   print(a)
   return a

calculation(1, 2)
```

To print the return value, you would do `print(calculation(1,2))`.